# PHP: exec of python Script not working on the Raspberry PI 2

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi2

My problem is that I've got a python Script in the Webspace folder of my RaspPI my PHP Script should call but it doesn't.
I already set the python file permission to everyone.
But still i can't get this to work.
I tried several solutions but none of them helped me.
Here's what I did so far:

**index.htm**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="photo.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" value="Take photo" name="test">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**photo.php**

```
    if(isset($_POST['test']))
    {

    shell_exec('/var/www/photoburst.py');



    echo'photo saved';



    }
    else 
    {
    echo'Error.';
    }
    ?>
```

I cant find any errors so please help me fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for the photoburst.py file. Is there no other feedback on what went wrong?

Comment: Thats the Problem,the code works fine when I execute it in python.The Problem is PHP.I think its because of a permission or something.The python Code is really not the problem...

Comment: What happens when you run the photoburst.py file directly from the shell?

Comment: Try something like this `$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/photoburst.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;` this requires that photoburst.py has the shebang line at the top to invoke the python interpreter and that the file is executable.

Comment: * failed to open vchiq instance this is what i get when using you're method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone having the same problem: This is the solution:
First you need to give full write/read and execute permission to the camera module AND the var/www folder. 
This is done by typing:

---

sudo chmod 777 /var/www
sudo chmod 777 /dev/vchiq

---

into the Shell command line
maybe you need to get root rights by typing

---

sudo bash

---

before.

Next thing is to change the image save path folder to var/www because this now is fully accessible.

When done so, you need to modify photo.php like that

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['test']))
{

$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/photoburst.py');
 $output = shell_exec($command);
  echo $output;



echo'Saved!';



}
else 
{
echo'No Info submitted from the form.';
}
?>
```

Last thing is to tell the python file to, well be a python file with the shebang line now:
When done, photoburst.py should look similar to this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import picamera
import datetime

camera=picamera.PiCamera()





camera.capture('/var/www/'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("IMG %T%B%d%Y")+'.jpg')
camera.close()
```

So if you followed these steps, you probably be able to take a photo with the raspberry cam through PHP.
A big thank you to all of the posters here.
Without your help I would never have found out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your file has execution permission `chmod a+x /var/www/photoburst.py`
- Instead you could call `/usr/bin/python /var/www/photoburst.py` and see if that works

What Linux are you running? Raspbian? N00bs?

Comment: I'm running Raspbian.I tried your shell command and changing my code to /usr/bin/python /var/www/photoburst.py but still it doesn't execute.Do i have to change something more?

Comment: how do you verify that it is not executing? Maybe it executes but it running into trouble? Try executing it from the command line by just executing it direclty...

`pyhton /var/www/photoburst.py`

Comment: Also, double-check that you PHP installation is not running in *safe-mode*. That would not allow the usage of cmd/backtick/exec... This functionality is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: import time
import picamera
import datetime

camera=picamera.PiCamera()
  
 


  
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("IMG %T%B%d%Y")+'.jpg')
camera.close()
  
this is why i know it doesn't excecute.when running from shell this script takes a picture with the raspberry cam.What is shebang?

Comment: The shebang should probably look like 

`#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: what do you get if you run `pyhton /var/www/photoburst.py` on the command line?

Comment: Nothing,because the script works fine. But I found the Solution thanks to shuttle87. The error message which is displayed if using his part of code helped me to figure out the Problem. The user www-data has no access to the Camera Module. Second I needed to change the path where images should be saved because www-data isn't allowed to save on desktop, too.